# Android: How to find bitmap extents, which will not crash the app?

Tags: android, bitmap, crash

While trying to decode a bitmap from a web stream I'm occasionally crashing the app in case the bitmap extents exceed the memory size allowed.

In order to overcome this I'm using the strategy explained here:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Since I'm using a careful approach with width and height of 500x500 as input for calculateInSampleSize, I'm having no troubles with memory issues anymore, but customers complain about the poor image quality of the downscaled image.

Because there seem no obvious way to me to determine *the* bitmap extents, which will NOT crash, I'm unfortunately forced to try with a rather low value (here 500x500), whereas in a concrete case 1000x1000 would also work fine.

Is there any way to find out, what bitmap extent as input for calculateInSampleSize is the maximum extent, which will not crash the app in subsequent calls to e.g. decodeByteArray?

Regards

Comment: Did you enable largeHeap already?

Comment: No. But I found an answer. Will post that right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found a way. I like to share it here, maybe there are some PROs and CONs.

1) First (that is not changed from my original code) I'm determining the original extent of the bitmap, which is available in a byte[] to the function:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length, options);

    /* Here we have the original dimensions of the bitmap */
    int iH = options.outHeight;
    int iW = options.outWidth;
    String iT = options.outMimeType;
```

2) Then I'm trying to find the best scaling value, which will finally produce a bitmap not larger then 2048x2048, because this seems to be the OpenGL limit (at least the traces tell me something like that)

```
    int rh = iH;
    int rw = iW;
    int sz = 1;

    while (true) {
        rh = Math.round((float)iH/(float)(sz));
        rw = Math.round((float)iW/(float)(sz));
        if (rh <= 2048 && rw <= 2048)
            break;
        sz++;
    }
```

3) Finally I'm creating the new (probably downscaled image) and trying to catch a possible memory overflow error here too. I could re-iterate with an increasing positive delta to sz then, but I decided to just return null.

```
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inSampleSize = sz;
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length, options);
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
    }
    return bm;
```

That works fine for me.

Comment: The opengl limit will not crash the app AFAIK, it will just make the image not appear on modern devices without warning.

Comment: You are right. No crash if the attempt to display that image doesn't cause an uncaught OutOfMemory exception.

Comment: Have you ever caught an OutOfMemory exception? You'd probably still be better off enabling largeHeap.